# Vimeo Upload Video Request Entity Too Large 413 Error, RestSharp

Tags: c#, vimeo, restsharp, vimeo-api

I'm using RestSharp to try to upload a video to Vimeo, but I keep getting an `Http 413 RequestEntityTooLarge` error.  I think I'm sending just the bytes and not the encoded video, so I'm not sure what is wrong.  This is my code:

```
//construct request
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(endpoint);
request.Method = Method.PUT;

//add headers
request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", _accessToken));
request.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.ToString());
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
request.AddParameter(mimeType, fileData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

//allow for the transfer of larger files (10min timeout)
request.Timeout = 2400000;

// Upload the file
IRestResponse uploadResponse = _client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: How big is the file you're trying to upload in bytes?

Comment: It says that the file is 56657198 bytes, roughly 54MB.  Would that be too big for Vimeo?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your code. Vimeo is telling you what's wrong; The file you're uploading is too large for them to accept.

Double check that your `fileSize` variable is correct. If incorrect, Vimeo may thing you're trying to upload a file that's much larger than it really is.

If the file is, in fact, too large, compress it using any number of file compressors and then upload that.

**UPDATE:** According to [this forum post](https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:286159), you need to make sure you're not encoding your file in any way.

Comment: So the file I'm trying to upload is 54MB.  The `fileSize` variable is `56657198 `.

Comment: Same problem here with a 500kb file